# How to reset to default value bsDateRangePicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create reactive forms with Angular 9. And also I use ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to use daterangepicker, when I use form.reset() function, function clears the input field.
But I just want to reset it to default value.

When page loaded, it shows me default value. But if I reset it, it does not.

Here it is my html file:

```
<form id="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-group p-2">
<div class="input-group ">
<input value="null" type="text" 
       class="form-control" formControlName="dateRange"                                         
       #dp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker 
       [bsConfig]="{ rangeInputFormat : 'DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm:ss', dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YY, 
       HH:mm:ss',showWeekNumbers: false, isAnimated: true, containerClass: 'theme-blue' } ">
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="clearAllForms()" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
</form>
```

and ts file:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateRange: new FormControl([
        new Date(this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() - 7)),
        new Date()
      ])})

clearAllForms(){
     myForm.reset()
}
```

How to reset it to default value. Is  that possible?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass in the wanted default values (here an array of `Date`object) as a map inside the `reset` method, where key is the form control name and value the value of the control.

```
clearAllForms(){
  this.myForm.reset({
    dateRange: [new Date(), new Date()]
  });
}
```

Comment: it works. I forgot to add it in reset function as a paramater. thank you very much